# Make a button execute 2 terminal commands

Tags: keyboard

I have an RGB keyboard but the switch key is not working on Linux .
To switch light on I need to run this command `xset led on` and to turn it off I need to run this `xset led off`
Can I add these commands as a shortcut to a button with a status check before to run on or off command?

Comment: Yes, you can if you can read the current status. Then a script can check the current value of the status and change to the other value accordingly.

Comment: I know but i'm not a programmer.

Comment: `xset q` lists all current settings, so a script will need to analyze that output. Add some of this information and output for your computer to your question, and someone may be able to brew a little script for you.

Answer (score 0):

i just faced the same problem you had and one easy solution will be to set custom keyboard shortcuts one for xset led on and one for xset led off, and you can toggle between them very easy.